# Código para inverter sequência de não-vogais encerrando com status zero

Tags: c, operadores, lista-encadeada, char

Estou implementando a função `decodificar`, que tem como objetivo chamar funções auxiliares para inverter todas as sequências de não-vogais. Por exemplo, se a palavra for "monstros legais", seguirá para "mortsnol segais".

```
void inverterNvs(NO* elemento, NO* anteriorAoElemento) {
    if (elemento->prox != NULL) {
        inverterNvs(elemento->prox, elemento);
    }
    elemento->prox = anteriorAoElemento;
}


bool verificaSequencia(NO* dado) {
    if (dado->letra != 'a' || dado->letra != 'e' || dado->letra != 'i' || dado->letra != 'o' || dado->letra != 'u'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

void decodificar(LISTA* resp) {
    NO* pNv = NULL; // Primeira não-vogal encontrada.
    NO* ultNv = NULL; // Última não-vogal encontrada.

    NO* atual = resp->inicio; // Ponteiro para percorrer a lista.

    /* Laço para percorrer toda lista. */
    while (atual->prox != NULL) {

        /* Enquanto atual apontar para uma não-vogal. */
        if (verificaSequencia(atual)) {
            /* Salva o primeiro caso encontrado de não-vogal. */
            pNv = atual;

            /* Procura na lista o último caso de não-vogal. */
            while (verificaSequencia(atual->prox)) {
                atual = atual->prox;
            }
            /* Quando a próxima letra for uma vogal, então foi atingido o fim da sequência de não-vogais. */
            ultNv = atual;

            /* Se existir uma sequência de não-vogais, ou seja, pNv e ultNv não apontarem para o mesmo elemento, então a troca de posições deve ser efetuada. */
            if (pNv != ultNv) {
                /* Chama uma função recursiva para efetuar a troca de posições sem precisar criar uma nova lista. */
                inverterNvs(pNv->prox, pNv);
            }
        }

        /* Move para o próximo elemento. */
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se meu código resolve o problema e como completá-lo para que ele funcione, pois as inversões não estão sendo feitas. Meu program está terminando com status 0, de acordo com o CodeBlocks, mesmo após chamar a função `decodificar`. **Código completo:** https://repl.it/KrQg/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logica que está a utilizar faz sentido, e responde ao problema, mas existem vários pormenores da implementação que não estão corretos.

Começando pela inversão dos nós:

```
void inverterNvs(NO* elemento, NO* anteriorAoElemento) {
    if (elemento->prox != NULL) {
        inverterNvs(elemento->prox, elemento);
    }
    elemento->prox = anteriorAoElemento;
}
```

Neste caso a navegação está a ser feita até ao `NULL` para inverter apenas um trecho da frase, o que não responde ao que o método pretende fazer, que é para na consoante final. Ou seja se queremos inverter "nstr" de "n" até "r" então temos de indicar o "r" de alguma maneira caso contrário vai até ao fim da frase.

Logo pode-se alterar incluindo um ponteiro de fim:

```
void inverterNvs(NO* elemento, NO* anteriorAoElemento, NO* fim /*novo fim aqui*/) { 
    if (elemento != fim) { //teste agora com o fim em vez de NULL
        inverterNvs(elemento->prox, elemento, fim);
    }
    elemento->prox = anteriorAoElemento;
}
```

A função `verificaSequencia`:

```
bool verificaSequencia(NO* dado) {
    if (dado->letra != 'a' || dado->letra != 'e' || dado->letra != 'i' || dado->letra != 'o' || dado->letra != 'u'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Também não está correta no `if` pois valida com ou(`||`) quando devia validar com e(`&&`). Se tivermos um `'e'` o primeiro teste de `dado->letra != 'a'` dá `true` e como é com ou(`||`) já nem testa o resto e dá `true` como resultado quando deveria dar `false`.

Basta alterar o `if` para que fique:

```
if (dado->letra != 'a' && dado->letra != 'e' && dado->letra != 'i' && dado->letra != 'o' && dado->letra != 'u'){
```

A função `decodificar` é a que necessita de mais alterações para que responda totalmente á logica.

É necessário:

- Ajustar as condições dos 2 `while`
- Voltar a ligar o bloco invertido com o resto da lista
- Atualizar o `atual` após a inversão

Considerando tudo isso, fica agora assim (cortei os seus comentários para focar apenas nas alterações que eu fiz):

```
void decodificar(LISTA* resp) {
    NO* pNv = NULL;
    NO* ultNv = NULL;

    NO* atual = resp->inicio;

    //ponteiro necessário para voltar a ligar o bloco invertido com o resto
    NO* anterior = NULL; 

    //este while foi alterado de atual->prox!=NULL para atual!=NULL uma vez que o while
    //de dentro mexe também no atual e o atual=atual->prox do fim pode meter o atual 
    //a NULL fazendo com que atual->prox!=NULL pudesse dar erro aqui
    while (atual != NULL) {

        if (verificaSequencia(atual)) {
            pNv = atual;

            //se o while utiliza atual, é necessário não deixar passar o NULL senão
            //dá erro, e por isso adicionei aqui atual->prox != NULL &&
            while (atual->prox != NULL && verificaSequencia(atual->prox)) {
                atual = atual->prox;
            }

            ultNv = atual;

            if (pNv != ultNv) {

                //guardar o nó seguinte à inversão para depois voltar a ligar o bloco invertido
                NO* proximoOriginal = ultNv->prox;

                //chamada agora inclui também o ultNv como ponteiro de fim
                inverterNvs(pNv->prox, pNv, ultNv);

                //o pNv que era o primeiro é agora o ultimo, e por isso o seu prox
                //tem de apontar para o antigo próximo
                pNv->prox = proximoOriginal;

                //o ultNv que era o ultimo é agora o primeiro, e por isso o antes 
                //deste (o anterior) tem de agora apontar para ultNv. É necessário 
                //considerar o caso em que o anterior é nulo, que é quando inverte 
                //logo da primeira letra
                if (anterior == NULL){
                    resp->inicio = ultNv;
                }
                else {
                    anterior->prox = ultNv;
                }

                //o atual fica no ultimo após inversão
                atual = pNv;
            }
        }

        anterior = atual; //atualiza o anterior
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
}
```

Repare que tive que acrescentar tanto o ponteiro `anterior` com o ponteiro `proximoOriginal` para conseguir ligar o bloco invertido com a lista que já existia. Porque no quando é feita a inversão de `o"nstr"` para `o"rtsn"` o `o` continuava a apontar para o `n` quando deveria agora apontar para o `r`, que é o que faz a instrução:

```
anterior->prox = ultNv;
```

De igual forma o `n` que é agora o novo fim tem que apontar para a letra que vem a seguir a este bloco, que é o que é feito nesta instrução:

```
pNv->prox = proximoOriginal;
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone a funcionar](https://ideone.com/1lwTi5)

Comment: Sua resposta é exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @CaioIgnm De nada, boa sorte para o resto do trabalho

Comment: acabei de notar dois erros: a última letra está sendo ignorada(em "vai chover" a letra "r" não é tratada); entradas contendo frases com mais de duas palavras acabam com "non-zero status", por exemplo, "vai chover amanha".

Comment: @CaioIgnm o `"vai chover"` dá `"vaihc over"` que de acordo com a logica era o esperado. Qual era o resultado que `"vai chover"` deveria dar? E vejo o mesmo para `"vai chover amanha"` que devolve `"vaich ove ramahna"` que na minha otica era o esperado

Comment: @CaioIgnm O pormenor do ponto não foi indicado na pergunta, e por isso `"vai chover."` vai resultar em `"vaihc ove.r"`, que suspeito que não era o que queria ? É suposto programa ignorar caracteres de acentuação como `'?', '!','.'`,etc.. ?

Comment: Percebi dois erros: primeiro, quando a palavra passada termina com uma sequência de não-vogais, por exemplo "vai chover amanh.", o programa não funciona. Perceba que se a entrada foi algo do tipo "vai chover amanha.", o programa funciona perfeitamente, pois a palavra não termina em *sequencia* de não-vogais. Segundo, sua observação sobre o ponto está correta, ""vai chover."" deve ter como resultado "vaihc ove.r". Estou usando CodeBlocks 16 e, com este último exemplo, o programa não funciona

Comment: @CaioIgnm Isso tem a ver com o que eu disse. Isso não foi contemplado na logica logo um `.` é considerado como uma não vogal e por isso é invertido com o resto das não vogais adjacentes. Dai que eu tenha perguntado se o seu programa é suposto ignorar os pontos, assim como outros caracteres de acentuação

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65344/discussion-between-caioignm-and-isac).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode separar esse problema em dois pequenos problemas:

1. Encontrar a "sub lista" que contém a sequência de não vogais (consoantes)
2. Inverter uma lista simplesmente encadeada.

O primeiro problema de certa forma é mais fácil de resolver, você pode abordar de diversas maneiras possíveis. No código abaixo, eu utilizei de uma [Função Recursiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) chamada `InverteElementos`.

Todavia, é possível (e na minha opinião mais fácil de entender) criar uma nova lista temporária que servirá para auxiliar a inverter as posições da sequencia de não vogais.  Não tomei esse caminho por não saber como foram implementadas as funções de criar a sua estrutura `LISTA`, e também porque não sei se seu problema permite a utilização de memória auxiliar.

A função **`inverterNvs`**, percorre a lista simplesmente encadeada, membro por membro, e ao encontrar uma sequência de consoantes, efetua a troca das posições dos membros da sequência usando uma função recursiva.

Vale ressaltar que a função **`ehNaoVogal`** serve apenas para deixar o código mais legível.

```
void inverterNvs(LISTA* resp) {
    NO* pNv = NULL; // Primeira não-vogal encontrada.
    NO* ultNv = NULL; // Última não-vogal encontrada.

    NO* atual = resp->inicio; // Ponteiro para percorrer a lista.

    /* Laço para percorrer toda lista. */
    while (atual->prox != NULL) {

        /* Enquanto atual apontar para uma não-vogal. */
        if (ehNaoVogal(atual)) {
            /* Salva o primeiro caso encontrado de não-vogal. */
            pNv = atual;

            /* Procura na lista o último caso de não-vogal. */
            while (ehNaoVogal(atual->prox)) {
                atual = atual->prox;
            }
            /* Quando a próxima letra for uma vogal, então foi atingido o fim da sequência de não-vogais. */
            ultNv = atual;

            /* Se existir uma sequência de não-vogais, ou seja, pNv e ultNv não apontarem para o mesmo elemento, então a troca de posições deve ser efetuada. */
            if (pNv != ultNv) {
                /* Chama uma função recursiva para efetuar a troca de posições sem precisar criar uma nova lista. */
                inverteElementos(pNv->prox, pNv);
            }
        }

        /* Move para o próximo elemento. */
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
}

void inverteElementos(NO* elemento, NO* anteriorAoElemento) {
    if (elemento->prox != NULL) {
        inverteElementos(elemento->prox, elemento);
    }
    elemento->prox = anteriorAoElemento;
}

bool ehNaoVogal(NO* dado) {
    if (dado->letra != 'a' || dado->letra != 'e' || dado->letra != 'i' || dado->letra != 'o' || dado->letra != 'u'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, Marcos. Contudo, não foi possível fazer a inversão das não-vogais. Segue código para maiores detalhes: https://repl.it/Kdko/21

Answer (score 1):

Isto **não** é uma resposta directa à pergunta colocada, mas apenas uma solução
do problema posto.

Segue um filtro que usando expressões regulares procura apenas
as zonas críticas e escreve-as invertido. No caso vou usar `flex`, que gera
`C`:

```
%%
[^aeiou\n]{2,}  {for( int i=yyleng-1; i>=0; i--) putchar(yytext[i]) ;}
%%
```

Modo de usar:

```
$ flex -o filtro.c filtro.fl
$ cc filtro.c -o filtro -lfl
$ echo "monstros legais"| filtro
mortsnol segais
```

Por último esta substituição é trivial em linguagens que tenham
suporte bom para processamento de expressões regulares. Exemplo:

```
$ echo "monstros legais"| perl -pe 's/([^aeiou]{2,})/reverse($1)/ge'
mortsnol segais
```

Comment: Obrigado, JJoao. Como se trata de um trabalho acadêmico devo utilizar somente ponteiros e listas simplesmente encadeadas

Comment: @ CaioIgnm, OK.